# Importing subscriber into list while accepting welcome email

Tags: marketing-cloud

If set up a list to accept a welcome email. Then I import the subscribers into the list. Are the going to receive all of them welcome email?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details so that members can try and answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they will not. As per [**the documentation**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/solution_guides/welcome_email/):

> The system will only send a welcome email to a subscriber when a
>   subscriber is added or subscribes via the Subscription Center or Web
>   Collect. Welcome email does not currently support imports,
>   manually-created subscribers, Smart Capture, or API.